# Include php is throwing result in header

Tags: php, append

I am trying to use the php code to display a comment box on a page:

```
$object_id = 'article_12';
include('commentanything/php/loadComments.php');
```

For some reason the comment box is not appearing where i want it to appear,it keeps throwing the comment box to header, is there any way i can make it appear exactly where i want it to?, here is where i am trying to use it(not a complete code):

```
    <!--<h1 align="center" style="font-size:1.2em"><strong>'.$row['title'].'</strong></h1>-->

                            <div class="song-art"><a href="'.$this->url.'/mp3download/'.$row['id'].'/'.$this->genSlug($row['title']).'.html"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$row['art'].'&t=m&w=112&h=112" id="song-art'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['title'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].'"/></a></div>
                            <div class="song-top">
                                <div class="song-timeago">
                                        <a href="'.$this->url.'/mp3download/'.$row['id'].'/'.$this->genSlug($row['title']).'.html"><span id="time'.$row['id'].'">
                                            <div class="timeago'.$b.'" title="'.$time.'">
                                                '.$time.'
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div data-track-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-track-id="'.$row['id'].'" id="play'.$row['id'].'" class="track song-play-btn">
                                </div>
                                <div class="song-titles">
                                    <div class="song-author"><a onmouseover="profileCard('.$row['idu'].', '.$row['id'].', 0, 0);" onmouseout="profileCard(0, 0, 0, 1);" onclick="profileCard(0, 0, 1, 1);" href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$row['username'].'">'.realName($row['username'], $row['first_name'], $row['last_name']).'</a></div>
                                    <div class="song-tag">
                                    <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=explore&filter='.$tag.'">'.$tag.'</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="song-title">
    <div class="track-link"><h2 style="font-size:1.0em">
    <!--<a href="'.$this->url.'/mp3download/'.$row['id'].'/'.$this->genSlug($row['title']).'.html" id="song-url'.$row['id'].'"><div id="song-name'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</div></a>-->
    </h2></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="player-controls">
                                <div id="song-controls'.$row['id'].'">
                                    <div id="jp_container_123" class="jp-audio">
                                        <div class="jp-type-single">
                                                <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                                                    <div class="jp-progress">
                                                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="track-actions-container">                                                        

                            </div>
                                '.$extra_links.'
                                '.$seo_links.'

                            '.$comment.'

                            '.$charts.'
                        </div>';


$object_id = 'article_12';
include('commentanything/php/loadComments.php');    



                    $start = (isset($row['extra_id'])) ? $row['extra_id'] : $row['id'];
                }
            }
```

I am trying to display it right after '.$charts.' but it keeps showing up in header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's  looking like you haven't worked to match HTML in index and loadComments.php .

first copy your loadComments.php code in place of include('commentanything/php/loadComments.php');

and check for html/css errors. It's there.

And if it failed too, your php/html nesting is wrong which i cant tell because u don't have even used  to know us how and where u are stuffing php. You simply added variables in above displayed code